# Is there a way to compress this javascript code down more?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have written the following code which works, but im wondering can I make it any smaller.

```
$(document).ready(function ()

            $('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

                    $('#' + this.id).removeClass('watermark');

                }
            });

            $('.datepickerTarget').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");

        });
```

I guess im trying to understand what the line:

```
$('.datepickerTarget').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

Is doing. Is this a constuctor? Where do I find what i can put in this line? Is it just a method? Not sure about the syntax.

Hope someone can help me understand so I can shorten this code make it a bit more slick...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: You've got 8 lines of code, 5 of which actually do something, and those line represent incredibly huge chunks of code in the background - don't worry about shrinking it any more, it's already shrunk a lot.

Comment: It seems you lost people after the first question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    $('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#' + this.id).removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});
```

You can set the date format when the object is constructed by passing it as a parameter to the "constructor" of the date time object.

If you are worried about size, look into JavaScript compression. I use the [YUI compression algorithm](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Answer (score 4):

Making code *more slick* is a step towards making it unmaintainable.

If you're having a hard time figuring out how to make it smaller, think of the hard time you will have remembering what the hell it does when you look at it in 6 months.

Comment: Excellent comment!  We could code everything in C after all - no wait, machine code, no wait, micro code, etc...  The reason of any high level language is for programmers to understand and maintain programs and thus readability (as well as actual functionality!) is really important.

Comment: I think you're right though: I should have made it a comment. I had no intention of it being the accepted answer (and I do certainly see the benefit of having the dateFormat initialization coupled with the rest of the datepicker). I just wanted to suggest that this type of question should be asked of oneself very conservatively.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        $('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

                $('#' + this.id).removeClass('watermark');

            },
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    });
```

You can add that option right in the initialization options of datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the `dateFormat` property along with the `onSelect` in on single call here:

```
$('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $('#' + this.id).removeClass('watermark');
            },
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { $(this).removeClass('watermark'); }, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look very compressed at all already - usually, compressing Javascript boils down to obfuscating it, in a sense: removing all unnecessary characters, including newlines and even renaming methods to something much less (or not at all) descriptive. You might mean compress in another sense, such as removing non-required code to minimise not only the amount, but also  ridding code of superfluous work - such would be removing redundancy.

With that out of the way, and moving onto your second question, yes, that is something of a constructor, or "initializer"; used to instantiate the plugin and supply required arguments as parameters. You should be able to find out which parameters are supported in two ways:

- Read the documentation for the plugin
- Look at the source file and read the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepickerTarget').datepicker({
     onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                   $('#' + this.id).removeClass('watermark');
               },
     dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

it's not really actually less lines, but it's tidier to move the dateFormat into the datepicker initiation.

you really should have a look at the documentation!